# SSL Certificate Integrate in ASP.NET MVC Static website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy-api

ASP.NET MVC Static website developed and deployed, domain and host already taken from Go-Daddy.

Website is up and running no issues in that.

**Without SSL:**

[image]

Now planning to take a SSL Certificate,

1. Which one need take, any types in certificates?
2. How to integrate that certificate in my deployed application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are hosting via IIS, the cert is reside on the IIS server. You publish the same way except that now you are using port 443 instead of 80

Comment: **@Leong San**, any reference links for the same?